# U-Boot shell - show memory usage (like Linux free command)

Tags: memory, u-boot

Is there any way of displaying memory usage from U-Boot?
I mean operation memory - like sdram - not mmc..

Ideally from shell but I can be happy also with C command as I compile U-Boot myself.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, in terms of free(1) type information.  We simply do not do that type of accounting and then have the ability to report it back.  The closest we have is 'bdinfo' (or bdi for short):

```
> bdinfo
...
DRAM bank   = 0x00000000
-> start    = 0x80000000
-> size     = 0x40000000
```

Answer (score 0):

U-boot commands documentation is available here:

http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/Manual

The acutal set of commands depend on the built version/branch .

Comment: thanks for the resource .. but the question was which command.. :)

Comment: you could search for 'memory' or similar in that manual.  To do that, type `Ctrl-F` or maybe `/` to enter search mode (note: this may vary depending on your browser) and then type `memory` and hit enter.

Comment: @cas haha.. dont make fun of me :D I already searched but found nothing.. there is a section memory commands and there is nothing as list memory usage or so.. I searchded the uboot help, searched the net but couldn find any info on if its even possible for uboot to get that information.. there is command for checking whats on certain address but I do not want to search the memory byte-by-byte of course..